# Hadoop Partitioning by Time Sequence

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, streaming, reduce

I am trying to partition my map outputs by a date, however I am not having any luck.

My map output is in the form:

2012-01-01\tsome text here

Using the KeyFieldBasedPartitioner, I am trying to partition each map output by date, so each year would have 365 partitions.

The following options have not worked for me:
map.output.key.field.separator=-
mapred.text.key.partitioner.options=-k1,3.2 #Each reducer matches the second character of the 'day' field in my key, so 01, 11, 21, and 31 are sent to the same reducer).

Is it possible to partition off of the combination of two characters?

Answer (score 0):

mapred.text.key.partitioner.options=-k1,3.2 means to use the first key field(2012 in your example) and part of third field (\tsome txet) as the partitioner. Obviously. it's not to "partition each map output by date".
Maybe you can try the following options:
**map.output.key.field.separator=\t mapred.text.key.partitioner.options=-k1**

FYI: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/KeyFieldBasedPartitioner.html